# Vapor Connection refused (errno 61)

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm seeing the following error when trying to run my Vapor 3 application:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: NIO.ChannelError.connectFailed(NIO.NIOConnectionError(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 3306, dnsAError: nil, dnsAAAAError: nil, connectionErrors: [NIO.SingleConnectionFailure(target: [IPv4]127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:3306, error: connection reset (error set): Connection refused (errno: 61))]))

It used to work just fine.
What can I do?

Comment: I was getting this kind of error when I was trying to connect with hostname but should have been using a socket file - there's an init that takes unixDomainSocketPath

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It might be the case that the database server is not yet running.

For MySQL, open a terminal and run the command:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

For Postgres, do:

```
$ brew services start postgres
```

Then, try again to run the project. It should work again now :)

---

<sup>Taken from [here](https://medium.com/@caleb.kleveter/i-think-you-are-getting-that-because-the-database-server-is-not-booted-up-so-your-app-connect-to-a6cc84f4c533).</sup>